# PHP render image file

Tags: php, image, apache

What are my options when it comes to rendering an image file? Let's say I have one saved in foo/bar.png

Currently I know I can use `readfile()` or better yet, `X-Sendfile` (I'm on Apache). What are some other ways to do it that are better than using `readfile()`?

I want to output the image to the browser (Content-Type: image/png)

Comment: What are you trying to do with bar.png?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I just want to output it to the browser.

Like, Content-Type: image/png

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Could you elaborate, I searched, but it always says that PHP automatically does this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *best* solution is to allow your webserver (Apache) to serve the content itself. If PHP must be used instead, all you need to to is ensure that the Content-Type is set to the appropriate value first:

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
```

Then use `readfile()` to send the image itself.

Comment: Okay, and the only way to do this is with X-sendfile? Is there a way in which a mod isn't needed?

Comment: I don't think X-Sendfile is even required for my solution? I tested it on a mostly unmodified nginx server and it worked fine; no need for any Apache mods.

Comment: No, I mean by allowing Apache to serve the content itself.

Comment: That's a question that I don't know how to answer other than "put the files you want to send in the document root". It's been a long time since I've used Apache. Maybe look into mod_alias?

Comment: Okay, thanks. But, I think I'll try Ignacio's chunked transfer solution.